# Insert class in all spring model

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have on user registration form, a startup controler (with request method get) that loads the user class to that form and a post method to save the user. Everything uses spring. But now I want to move the registration form to a popup in the header file and every page will import that. 
The problem is, I don't want to insert the user class in all Get methods. What I really want is to "inject" in all models the user class without having to do something in all other methods.

Is this possible to do? And how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [Spring 3.2](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.2.html#new-in-3.2-webmvc-controller-advice), there is a @ControllerAdvice class level annotation introduced.  If you place your model attribute in a separate class with @ControllerAdvice, it will be available to all controllers. For example add getUserForm() in the @ControllerAdvice annotated class, instead of your original controller(s):

@ControllerAdvice
public class ModelAttributeAdvice {

```
@ModelAttribute
public SearchForm getUserForm(){
    return new UserForm();
}
```

}

Comment: This worked Thanks!! Btw, if I have a list to also include in the form, there is any other better way or the best ways is to use controllerAdvice?

Comment: If the list also applies to all Controllers, I think its fine to include in same way in the class that has @ControllerAdvice. Otherwise, if it only applies to a specific page, it would be better to leave it in only the Controller class it applies to.